# exist-db with Ajax: waiting and receiving times

Tags: ajax, xquery, exist-db

when doing AJAX calls with XQuery in exist-db I noticed some unusual discrepancies between waiting and receiving times. Usually these are far too small to notice, but recently I ran into a problem.

I need to pass a whole 5 MB response at once and I noticed that while evaluating the call in eXide it takes somewhere below 3 seconds, which is decent since it is a complex call. But when passing it via Ajax I noticed that it takes between 8 and 11 seconds in total, with almost equal waiting and receiving time.  Now 5 MB is not really that much, so I was surprised it took so long to transfer it. So I ran the .xql script in an empty browser page, and saw the same issue, 4-5 seconds waiting times and just as much receiving time.

I tried changing the output method to raw text, json, etc but there seems to be no difference whatsoever. Am I missing something and do I need to configure eXist in a certain way to increase these speeds or should I get used that this is just how it's supposed to work for anything over 1 megabyte?

Comment: Which version of eXist?

Comment: The most recent stable release, 6.0.1.

Comment: Basically, there are three things that are done here: 1) running the query; 2) serializing the result; 3) transferring the result.
A first step to tackle this is to look where the individual bottlenecks are. For the query, there’s the profiler in Monex, which you should run separately for both eXide and external queries and see whether there’s a difference. Use your browser’s dev tools to look at transfer speeds in eXide and other cases.
Depending on what your query does, there might also be a difference due to streaming the results vs. creating a complete response to send at once.

Comment: I would put timestamps at every major step and report them all out with the result, it would narrow down where the bottleneck is. I've found this useful for optimizing certain processes including AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you folks, these were some good suggestions. So I profiled the query in Exide and the interesting part is that the waiting time is usually the same (or 1 second longer in a lot of instances, not sure why that is), in any case, it goes for 3 or 4 seconds. But then the receiving time is far shorter in Exide, it's only about 400 milliseconds, compared to the 5 seconds via AJAX. Then I ran the xql directly in a browser and I get the same 5 seconds waiting time, so this seems to be an issue with serializing or transferring the result and I'm still not sure why that is or how it can be fixed.